# Null cookie - python mechanize

Tags: python, cookies, web-scraping, mechanize, python-requests

I am trying to login to site using Python but I have a problem with one of the cookies being set to null:

> Set-Cookie: EfebSsoAuthCookie=null; domain=domain.com;
>   expires=Fri, 31-Dec-1999 23:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

When I am using firefox this cookie is set properly but I can't make it work in Python.

```
import mechanize
import cookielib
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]

cj = cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cj)

url = "url"
response = br.open(url)

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form['Email'] = "mail@gmail.com"
br.form['Password'] = "pass"
response = br.submit()

br.select_form(nr=0)
response1 = br.submit()
print response1.read()
```

I also tried with requests but the result was the same.

Comment: I believe you have to get the Cookie after going to the url, instead of setting it before?

Comment: How can I achieve it? Set-cookie is a response from server.